# PHP file Uploads not Working

Tags: php, excel, file-upload, amazon-ec2

I'm working on a web application in php that allows users to upload files with a specified structure (file type could be cvs or excel sheets) and the app will extract data from the files and insert them into a database.

I can't get my app to upload files and I've been trying for 2 days, I checked the php.ini for max upload size ,max post size , file uploads on, temp directory set to /tmp which is accessible by all users.

I also checked the syntax of  php and html and made sure I was using the right encoding type, I also checked the permissions of the upload directory but the _FILES variable is always empty, note : my web server is hosted on amazon ec2 running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

here's one of the codes I tried and it's output:

```
<?php
        echo $_FILES['file']['error'];
        print_r($_FILES);
        echo $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
?>

<html>
<header>
<title> Test Page</title>
</header>
<body>
<form action="Test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/formdata">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

and the outputted echo is only Array ( ) whether I upload a file or not.

anyone faced something like this before ?

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` makes sense, however `echo $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];` does not

Comment: Try this: enctype = "multipart/form-data". In your code it is enctype="multipart/formdata". Its may be help you.

Comment: Thank you Kashish , it works now, I just can't believe i spent two days researching and missed this typo, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        session_start();

        $file_tmp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        header("Test.php");
     }
 ?>

<html>
  <header>
     <title> helllllllo </title>
  </header>
  <body>
       <form action="form-validation" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >

        <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
          <label>
          <span>Profile Image</span>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="file" onchange="readURL(this);" data-val="true" style="margin-bottom:10px;" />
          <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
              <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" style="width: 100px; display: none; margin-bottom:10px;" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
       </form>
<script>

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').show().attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

</script>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```